# Is it possible to create inherited SqlDataTable in SqlDataSet. Devart dotconnect

Tags: sql-server, dotconnect

The problem is that when I redeclare standard SqlDataTable to my CustomSqlDataTable inside SqlDataSet. It works until you change the SqlDataSet that contain your custrom dataTable. After any change in SqlDataset it recreate code of own definition and all dataTables again becomes standard SqlDataTable. How to avoid it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The MyTalbeDataTable class (inherits Devart.Data.SqlServer.SqlDataTable), which is a part of a Devart typed DataSet, is generated with a "partial" keyword. Therefore, you can create a separate MyClass.cs file and extend a "predefined" functionality of MyTalbeDataTable. The code within MyClass.cs will not be wiped out because this is a custom file.